# Find the minimum and maximum integers in an array, without using builtins

Tags: code-golf, number, array

### Challenge

Given an array of integers, received from stdin, function arguments, program arguments, or some other method:

Output *only* the minimum and maximum numbers in the array, through a return value, stdout, or other fitting methods.

### Example session

```cpp
> minmax( {0, 15, 2, 3, 7, 18, -2, 9, 6, -5, 3, 8, 9, -14} )
-14 18
```

### Reference implementation

```cpp
// C++14

void minmax(std::vector<int> v) {
    int min = v[0]; int max = v[0];
    for(auto it : v) {
        if (*it < min)
            min = *it;
        if (*it > max)
            max = *it;
    }
    std::cout << min << ' ' << max << std::endl;
}
```

### Rules

- You may not use a built-in function to calculate the values.
- Standard loopholes disallowed.
- Creative implementations encouraged.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins but will not be selected.

### Clarifications

- If the array contains 1 element you need to output it twice.
- If the minimum and maximum values are the same, you need to output them both.

Comment: Anti-Dupe Information: Built ins are explicitly disallowed, and there are no strings in the array

Comment: Is it allowed to output a single value if min and max are the same or do we have to output the same value twice?

Comment: @MartinEnder Same value twice.

Comment: This is a [do X without Y challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/45941), which aren't particularly interesting.

Comment: @Mego Here the Y is just using built-in isn't it?

Comment: ugh, maybe I should have disallowed sorting

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Try the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) next time.

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Yet you used it yourself [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90847/48934).

Comment: @LeakyNun That's because it makes for the shortest solutions. I encouraged creative methods...

Comment: @Mego sure, i'll try

Comment: Can we assume that there will be at least 2 elements in the array?

Comment: @LeakyNun No, there can be 1

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Will there be 0?

Comment: @LeakyNun no, 1 or more

Comment: Seriously, *use the Sandbox*. Your changes to the challenge have invalidated every single answer.

Comment: @Mego Not every answer. Only like 5 of them. These were clarifications that were answers to questions people asked in the comments.

Comment: "Only like five of them" enough said...

Comment: Is a function that picks the largest of exactly two elements (in contrast to the largest of a whole array) allowed or does it count as a forbidden built-in?

Comment: @nimi Allowed...

Comment: _I encouraged creative methods_ No, you encouraged short solutions, by tagging it `code golf`

Comment: May I assume that a variable holds the length of the array (number of elements, regardless of size)? My language has 0-indexed arrays that contain an unlimited number of values, all of which are initialised to zero. If I request the value of `a[7]`, but there were only five elements in the array, I'll get `0` and never know that something went wrong.

Comment: @Joe he uses a vector class/template instead of a true array. He makes use of the fact that he can safely iterate from start to end because the length is stored. It seems like you should be able to as well.

Comment: As said Luis Mendo Yes, everyone is just posting "i sort your array using a built-in and take first and last", in different languages, not really creative :x

Comment: Well, to be fair, I immediately qualified `sort` as forbidden (isn't it a builtin...) when reading the challenge. It's basically a superset of minmax.

Comment: What are builtin, is there a meta topic about that?

Comment: why they are all using sort

Comment: what's the number range that must do? must be signed?

Answer (score 29):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Ṣ.ị
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmiLuG7iw&input=&args=WzAsIDE1LCAyLCAzLCA3LCAxOCwgLTIsIDksIDYsIC01LCAzLCA4LCA5LCAtMTRd)

Sort the array, and then takes the 0.5-th element.

Jelly uses 1-indexing, and floating points indexing means take its floor and its ceil.

So the 0.5-th element would give you the 0th element and the 1st element.

The 0th element is the last element.

Comment: Pretty Clever I'm wait for it.... Jelly!

Comment: Oh, so that would make finding the median trivial.

Comment: In which encoding is that three bytes?

Comment: @KonradRudolph [This](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: Don't you want the *first* and *last* elements, rather than the *first two* elements?  Or have I misunderstood your explanation?

Comment: @TobySpeight In 1-based indexing the 0th element is the last element.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I failed to read the last line in your answer.

Answer (score 12):

## Python, <s>61</s> <s>49</s> <s>37</s> <s>36</s> <s>34</s> 31 bytes

```python
lambda s:s.sort()or[s[0],s[-1]]
```

*-12 bytes thanks to RootTwo*

*Another -12 bytes thanks to chepner*

*-2 bytes thanks to johnLate*

*-3 bytes thanks to johnLate*

Comment: I changed the heading to Python because it works in Python 3 also.

Comment: You can golf off a dozen bytes: use `[::(len(s)-1)or 1]` for the first subscript.  And the second term can be shortened to `s[:len(s)<2]`.

Comment: At the cost of sorting the list twice, you can shave off another 12 bytes: `lambda s:sorted(s)[:1]+sorted(s)[-1:]`.

Comment: save 6 bytes by `lambda s:sorted(s)[::len(s)-1]`

Comment: The current version (`lambda s:sorted(s)[::len(s)-1]`) does not work for arrays with one element (`ValueError: slice step cannot be zero`). A possible fix would be `lambda s:sorted(s*2)[::len(s*2)-1]` (34 bytes).

Comment: 31 bytes: `lambda s:s.sort()or[s[0],s[-1]]`

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) <s>220</s> 218 bytes

```
(({}))([]){({}[()]<(([])<{({}[()]<([([({}<(({})<>)<>>)<><({}<>)>]{}<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}({}<><{}{}>){{}<>(<({}<({}<>)<>>)<>({}<>)>)}{}({}<>)<>>)}{}<>{}>[()]){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}({}<((())){{}{}([][()])}{}>)
```

[Try It Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdKXsoe31bKCldPCgoW10pPHsoe31bKCldPChbKFsoe308KCh7fSk8Pik8Pj4pPD48KHt9PD4pPl17fTwoKCkpPildKDw-KSl7KHt9KCkpPD59e30oe308Pjx7fXt9Pil7e308Pig8KHt9PCh7fTw-KTw-Pik8Pih7fTw-KT4pfXt9KHt9PD4pPD4-KX17fTw-e30-WygpXSl7KHt9WygpXTwoe308Pik8Pj4pfXt9PD4-KX17fSh7fTw-KTw-KFtdWygpXSl7e317fShbXVsoKV0pfXt9KHt9PD4p&input=)

### Explanation

First it doubles the top value (in cast the list is only one long)

```
(({}))
```

Then it uses my bubble sort algorithm:

```
([]){({}[()]<(([])<{({}[()]<([([({}<(({})<>)<>>)<><({}<>)>]{}<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}({}<><{}{}>){{}<>(<({}<({}<>)<>>)<>({}<>)>)}{}({}<>)<>>)}{}<>{}>[()]){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)}{}
```

Then it picks up the top value of the stack (i.e. the min)

```
({}<...>)
```

Then it pops until the height of the stack is one:

```
((())){{}{}([][()])}{}
```

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```
a=>[a.sort((x,y)=>x-y)[0],a.pop()]
```

`sort` sorts in-place, so I can just refer to the [0] index for the lowest value and `pop` the highest value from the array, however it does a string sort by default so I have to pass a comparator.

Comment: I don't think you need the `(x,y)=>x-y` part, unless using `sort()` with the default algorithm counts as a builtin.

Comment: @Scott But I don't want a lexical sort...

Comment: Right...  I didn't test it with numbers > 10 or < 0.  I didn't know `sort()` internally treats everything as strings - sorry!

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 18 bytes

```
Sort[#][[{1,-1}]]&
```

Sorts the array and extracts the first and last values.

Answer (score 5):

## R, 31 bytes

```
l=sort(scan());l[c(1,sum(l|1))]
```

Not *that* original, but hey !

Answer (score 5):

## ARM Machine Code, 26 bytes

Hex dump (little endian):

```
6810 4601 f852 cb04 4560 bfc8 4660 4561 bfb8 4661 3b01 d8f5 4770
```

This is a function, with no system call or library dependence. The encoding is Thumb-2, a variable (2 or 4 byte) encoding for 32-bit ARM. As one might imagine, there's no easy way to just sort and pick the first and last elements here. Overall there's nothing really that fancy going on here, it's more or less the same as the reference implementation.

Ungolfed assembly (GNU syntax):

```
.syntax unified
.text
.global minmax
.thumb_func
minmax:
    @Input: @r0 and r1 are dummy parameters (they don't do anything)
    @r2 - Pointer to list of integers (int*)
    @r3 - Number of integers to sort (size_t)
    @Output:
    @Minimum of the list in r0 (int)
    @Maximum in r1 (int)
    ldr r0,[r2] @min=r2[0]
    mov r1,r0 @max=min
    loop:
        @ip is intra-procedure call register, a.k.a. r12
        ldr ip,[r2],#4 @ip=*r2++
        cmp r0,ip
        it gt @if (r0>ip)
        movgt r0,ip @r0=ip
        cmp r1,ip
        it lt @if (r1<ip)
        movlt r1,ip @r1=ip
        subs r3,r3,#1
        bhi loop @while (--r3>0)
    bx lr @Return
```

Tested on the Raspberry Pi 3; here's the testing script (C99, input through argv):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
//First 2 arguments are dummies.
uint64_t minmax(int,int,int* array,size_t size);

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    int i;
    int array[argc-1];
    for (i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        array[i-1]=atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    uint64_t result = minmax(0,0,array,argc-1);
    printf("Minimum is %d, maximum is %d.\n",(unsigned)result,(unsigned)(result>>32));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 27 bytes

```
f x=(`foldl1`x)<$>[min,max]
```

In Haskell, `min` and `max` give minimum and maximum of two arguments, not of a list. I couldn't tell whether this is disallowed (it seems that instead only `minimum` and `maximum` would be disallowed) so please let me know if they are and I'll promptly delete this answer.

Comment: @nimi FGITW effect, sadly...

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 20 bytes

```
@(n)sort(n)([1,end])
```

This sorts the input vector and outputs the first and last value.

Answer (score 3):

### Actually, 5 bytes

```
S;F@N
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=UztGQE4&input=WzMsMiw1LDYsMV0)

Explanation:

```
S;F@N
S      sort
 ;     dupe
  F    first element
   @N  and last element
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
{Âø¬
```

**Explanation**

```
{     # sort list
 Â    # bifurcate
  ø   # zip
   ¬  # head
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=e8OCw7jCrA&input=WzAsIDE1LCAyLCAzLCA3LCAxOCwgLTIsIDksIDYsIC01LCAzLCA4LCA5LCAtMTRd)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
S5L)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UzVMKQ&input=WzAsIDE1LCAyLCAzLCA3LCAxOCwgLTIsIDksIDYsIC01LCAzLCA4LCA5LCAtMTRd)

#### Explanation

```
S    % Implicitly input the array. Sort
5L   % Push [1 0]. When used as a (modular, 1-based) index, this means "first and last"
)    % Apply as an indexing vector into the sorted array. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 29 bytes

```python
lambda s:s[s.sort():1]+s[-1:]
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/kQSoBu).

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>83</s> <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```
m,M;f(a,s)int*a;{for(m=M=*a;s--;++a)*a<m?m=*a:*a>M?M=*a:0;pr‌​intf("%i %i",m,M);}
```

Comment: the declaration can turn into `...f(a,s)int*a{...` per [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40266/46231)

Comment: You can combine the ternary expressions to get another 2 bytes off: `m,M;f(a,s)int*a;{for(m=M=*a;s--;++a)*a<m?m=*a:*a>M?M=*a:0;printf("%i %i",m,M);}`

Comment: In `gcc` you can replace `*a>M?M=*a:0` with `*a<M?:M=*a`

Answer (score 2):

## POSIX Awk, 44 bytes

```
awk '{for(;NF-1;NF--)if($1>$NF)$1=$NF}1' RS=
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
oOtT,Oh:T
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=b090VCxPaDpU&input=WzA6MTU6MjozOjc6MTg6XzI6OTo2Ol81OjM6ODo5Ol8xNF0&args=Wg)

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, <s>59</s> 52 bytes

```
void m(int[]x){x=sort(x);print(x[0],x[x.length-1]);}
```

Processing doesn't actually let me read from stdin that I've been able to find, and I don't know if its internal Java compiler supports lambdas (and its been so long since I've had to write serious Java that I don't remember how).

Comment: You can save bytes by removing spaces after `int[]`

Answer (score 1):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 12 bytes

```
:sor
ò2Gjkd
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=OnNvcgrDsjJHamtk&input=OQo4CjcKNgo1CjQKMwoyCjE)

Credit to DJMcMayhem for this.

Comment: `\o/` Yay, I'm no longer the only person to have ever used this language!

Comment: If the input is a single number, that number still has to be output twice

Comment: @LuisMendo hm, will work on that.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
q~$_(p;W>
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%24_(p%3BW%3E&input=%5B0%2015%202%203%207%2018%20-2%209%206%20-5%203%208%209%20-14%5D)

I'm really not good at CJam.

```
q~          e# eval input
  $         e# sort
   _        e# duplicate
    (       e# pop first
     p      e# print
      ;     e# remove array
       W>   e# get last element
```

Comment: The usual way to get the first element of a list is `0=` (but that unfortunately that doesn't save any bytes). Two other 9-byte solutions: `0W]q~$f=p` or the unnamed block `{$2*_,(%}`.

Comment: 8 bytes: `q~$(p)p;`. You can use `)` to get the last element like you use `(` to get the first.

Comment: @BusinessCat That's what I originally had, but it fails for single-element input.

Comment: @Pietu1998: Oh, you're right. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org) 13 bytes

```perl6
*.sort[0,*-1]
```

### Test:

```perl6
my &min-max = *.sort[0,*-1];

say min-max 1;
# (1 1)
say min-max (0, 15, 2, 3, 7, 18, -2, 9, 6, -5, 3, 8, 9, -14)
# (-14 18)
```

Comment: Darn, you beat me there!

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 34 bytes

```
x=sorted(input());print x[0],x[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL (Dyalog), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

-5 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer.

[According to the original poster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90835/find-the-minimum-and-maximum-integers-in-an-array-without-using-builtins/90910?noredirect=1#comment221579_90835), using *a function that picks the largest of exactly two elements (in contrast to the largest of a whole array)* [is] *allowed*. Therefore, the obvious solution is:

```apl
⌊/,⌈/
```

`⌊/` minimum-reduction

`,` followed by

`⌈/` maximum-reduction

---

More in the spirit of the challenge:

```apl
(⊃,⊢/)⍋⊃¨⊂
```

`(`

`⊃` first

`,` followed by

`⊢/` the last (lit. right-reduction)

`)` of

`⍋` the indices of the elements in ascending order

`⊃¨` each picks from

`⊂` the entire argument

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%28%u2283%2C%u22A2/%29%u234B%u2283%A8%u2282%290%2015%202%203%207%2018%20%AF2%209%206%20%AF5%203%208%209%20%AF14&run)

Comment: Wonder why this got downvoted.

Comment: Looks like [you can do it in 5 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90835/find-the-minimum-and-maximum-integers-in-an-array-without-using-builtins#comment221558_90835)...

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```
function a($a){sort($a);echo $a[0].end($a);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++ (g++), <s>148 133 131 122</s> 119 bytes

```
#import<map>
#import<vector>
[](std::vector<int>v){int a=v[0],b=a;for(int i:v)i<a?a=i:i<b?:b=i;printf("%d %d\n",a,b);};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY27CoMwGIX3PEWwCAmk0OuSiz6IdfgTa/kHTUjTLOKzW6V0KnQ6fOfCcSHsH84tOxyCj0kPECryhXx3yceKwCt52pv/paZlz9RJ@WGNY6oyn1ahYHJzaIU1oHof2WahzBw11GBQora1tAZViGvUs6LsaNndxkKAsFzNatkWA@DI@EQo/Xkx01GcxFlcxHVWa6FnmSsyL28)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>66</s> 65 bytes

Note: this doesn't use any `sort` builtin. Also, PHP 7 required for the null coalesce operator.

```
for(;n|$x=$argv[++$i];$x>$h&&$h=$x)$l=min($l??$x,$x);echo"$l,$h";
```

The `max` part is straightforward. The `min` part is a bit more elaborate. since in PHP `null` is less than `123`, null needs to be handled. For this I'm using the null coalesce operator. If `$l` is null, use the current number (`$x`) instead, then take the smaller of the 2 numbers.

Run like this:

```
php -d error_reporting=30709 -r 'for(;n|$x=$argv[++$i];$x>$h&&$h=$x)$l=min($l??$x,$x);echo"$l,$h";' -- 0 15 2 3 7 18 -2 9 6 -5 3 8 9 -14;echo
```

## 37 bytes (with sort)

Being allowed to sort makes it trivial (windows-1252 encoding):

```
php -d error_reporting=30709 -r '$a=$argv;echo$a[sort($a)],~ß,end($a);' -- 0 15 2 3 7 18 -2 9 6 -5 3 8 9 -14;echo
```

Sort returns `1` when successful, and the list of arguments will start with `-` which will be sorted as the first item, so we need item `1` to yield `min`. Therefore we happen to be able to use the return value of `sort` as the index, saving 2 bytes.

## Tweaks

- Use `n|"0"` to make `"0"` truthy to continue the loop, instead of `0 ."0"`. Saved a byte

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 115 bytes

```
String f(int[]i){int t=i[0],a=t,b=t;for(int c=0;c<i.length;c++){a=i[c]<a?i[c]:a;b=i[c]>b?i[c]:b;}return""+a+" "+b;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
String f(int[] i) {
    int t=i[0], a=t, b=t; // assigns a and b to i[0]
    for (int c=0; c < i.length; c++) { // loop through the array
        a=(i[c]<a) ? i[c] : a;
        b=(i[c]>b) ? i[c] : b; // assignment with ternary operator
    }
    return ""+a+" "+b; // returns a string
}
```

My first ever code "golf" solution.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <strike>68</strike> 58 bytes (without sorting)

Oh my first try in Golf: without explicit sort (and without min max).
Thanks to @ETHproductions for golfing tips!!

```
a=>(b=[],a.map(n=>b[n]=0),[b.indexOf(0),b.lastIndexOf(0)])
```

Does not work with negative integers.

Tried @Luis Mendo 's approach but got it 2 bytes longer... Cost for supporting negative numbers lol?

```
a=>[a.find(n=>a.every(e=>e>=n)),a.find(n=>a.every(e=>e<=n))]
```

Could get shorter if order of output is not important:

```
a=>a.filter(n=>a.every(e=>e>=n)||a.every(e=>e<=n))
```

Comment: Currying doesn't work in this case; the function is called internally as `f(a,b)`, and curried functions need to be called as `f(a)(b)`. (Try testing it out in a browser console.)

Comment: @ETHproductions You are correct. I should have provided an already sorted list as input when I was testing... Sorry for the misleading info. Other than a browser console, what ways are good ways to test ES6 code?

Comment: I sometimes use [this page](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html) to test my JS code, although this only supports what your browser does in terms of ES6 features. There are online places where you can run ES6 in any browser, but all the ones I found are very strict with the code (not accepting undeclared variables and the like).

Comment: Some golfing tips: you can get rid of the `let` and `return` and wrap everything in parentheses, like so: `a=>(b=[],a.map(n=>b[n]=0),[b.indexOf(0),b.lastIndexOf(0)])`

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks a lot! What does the `,` mean in the parentheses? (I don't know what is happening there)

Comment: In JS, when you have an expression like `(a,b,c)`, it returns the last value, i.e. `c`. For example, `("abc",[],3)+1` returns 4 (`3+1`).

Comment: @ETHproductions Oh thanks.. What are usages of this feature in real life?

Comment: Here are a [couple](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75305/42545) of [answers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74464/42545) I've written which use that trick.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

I wanted to try an answer without sorting:

```
a=>a.map(i=>i<n?n=i:i>x?x=i:0,n=x=a[0])&&[n,x]
```

Bonus recursive version, 53 bytes:

```
f=([i,...a],n=i,x=i)=>i+.5?f(a,i<n?i:n,i>x?i:x):[n,x]
```

Comment: Thanks. [Mine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94307/38392) also doesn't use sort.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 19 bytes

```julia
x->sort(x)[[1,end]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3v0LXrji/qESjQjM62lAnNS8lNvY/kOQqKMrMK8nJ00jTiDbQUTA01VEw0lEw1lEwB3IsdBR0gTxLHQUzIMsULG4B5usamsRqav7//x8A)

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 36 bytes

```
(\l->(head l,last l)).Data.List.sort
```

Would love to use `&&&` here but imports are so costly...

Comment: You can't just use `Data.List.sort` from what I know, you'd need to import it. You could specify Haskell and put LambdaBot in brackets which imports `Control.Arrow` as well, this would make it valid and save you 20 bytes (no need for `Data.List` at all).

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, <s>38</s> 23 bytes

<s>`def m(v) puts v.sort![0];$><<v[-1];end`</s>

```
->v{[v.sort![0],v[-1]]}
```

Thanks @Jordan!

Comment: You don't need the space after `def m(v)`. Regardless, you can save 15 bytes by using a lambda and just returning an array: `->v{[v.sort![0],v[-1]]}`.

Answer (score 0):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/), 17 bytes

```
O#`
$
¶$`
Ss`¶.+¶
```

Input and output are linefeed-separated.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=TyNgCiQKwrYkYApTc2DCti4rwrY&input=CjAKMTUKMgotMTQKMwo3CjE4Ci0yCjkKNgotNQozCjg)

#### Explanation

```
O#`
```

Sort lines by numerical value.

```
$
¶$`
```

Duplicate the entire input to make sure that the first and last element are distinct.

```
Ss`¶.+¶
```

Remove all intermediate lines, leaving only the minimum and maximum.

Answer (score 0):

## BASH 38

```
grep -o '[^ ]*'|sort -g|sed -n '1p;$p'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 38 bytes

```
[ natural-sort [ first ] [ last ] bi ]
```

Sort the sequence and get its first and last elements.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <strike>35</strike> 34 bytes

```python
lambda s:sorted(s+s[:1])[::len(s)]
```

Alternative version:

```python
lambda s:sorted(s+s)[::len(s)*2-1]
```

Old version, 35 bytes.

```python
lambda s:sorted(s+[s[0]])[::len(s)]
```

Fairly simple: take the input list, append the first element, sort it, then take the first and (length)th element of the resulting list. As the length of the input after appending an element is length + 1, this ends up taking the first and last element of said list, which are the minimum and maximum elements.

Comment: Though not the shortest answer in Python, this is very creative! +1

Comment: The 34-byte one doesn't work in Python 3; this works in both 2 and 3. Also, it was posted after this one.

Comment: @mbomb007 - fine, golfed. This is now tied for the shortest Python implementation, and as a bonus it works in both 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
S'he
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=S%27he&input=%5B4%2C1%2C5%2C7%5D&warnings=0&hex=0)

```
S    - sorted(input)
 'he - ^[0], ^[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 45 bytes

```
[dsa]dsAx[dsz]dsZx[dla>Adlz<Zs.z0<f]dsfxlzlaf
```

This is a fairly straightforward equivalent of the C++ reference code:

```
#Test data
0 15 2 3 7 18 _2 9 6 _5 3 8 9 _14

# Uses two variables: a for min, and z for max

# Functions A and Z simply store a copy to a and z respectively.  Call
# them both, to initialize the variables.
[dsa]dsAx
[dsz]dsZx

# Function f is the main work - define and call it
[
    dla>A                       # copy into a if lower
    dlz<Z                       # copy into z if higher
    s.                          # discard value
    z0<f                        # recurse until end of input
]dsfx

# print the result
lzlaf
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 60 bytes

```
n=>{System.Array.Sort(n);return new[]{n[0],n[n.Length-1]};};
```

A naïve method at 93 bytes:

```
n=>{var r=new[]{n[0],n[0]};foreach(int i in n){if(i<r[0])r[0]=i;if(i>r[1])r[1]=i;}return r;};
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 35 bytes

```
@(x)[x(all(t=x<=x')) x(sum(t)==1)]
```

This is an anoynymous function. [Try it at ideone](http://ideone.com/XGgLml).

The code avoids using sorting. Namely, it does all pairwise "less than or equal" comparisons between elements of the input. The minimum is the element for which *all* comparisons are true. The maximum is that for which *only one* comparison is true.

Answer (score 0):

## zsh, 22 bytes

```
(){echo $1 $_} ${(n)@}
```

defines a lambda function that prints its first arg (`$1`) and the last argument to the previous command (`$_`), and passes it `$@` after sorting it so the previous command becomes the invocation of that lambda

---

## zsh, 21 bytes

this only works fine if there's more than 1 argument :(

```
<<<"${${(n)@}/ * / }"
```

sorts `$@`, makes it a string and replaces everything from the first space to the last one with a single space, then passes it as input to cat with `<<<`

---

usage:

```
$ ./minmax 23 342 21 10
10 342
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 55 bytes

```
val s=args.map(_.toInt).sorted
print(s.head+" "+s.last)
```

To execute:

`$ scala minmax.scala 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 110 bytes

```
?ddsMsmzdsAsa[z1-:az0<S]dsSx[>R]s?[la;asM]sR[lM]sQ[lQxla1-dsa;al?xla0<N]dsNxlAsa[<R]s?[la;asm]sR[lm]sQlNxlmlMf
```

*Help me, `dc`ers! You are my only hope!*

Thanks to @seshoumara for finding that bug!

I'll add an explanation later. Here it is broken up a bit:

```
?dd sM sm
zd sA sa
[z 1- :a z0<S]dsSx
 [>R]s?
 [la;asM]sR
 [lM]sQ
[lQx la 1- dsa ;a l?x la0<N]dsNx
lA sa
 [<R]s?
 [la;a sm]sR
 [lm]sQ
lNx
lm lM f
```

Comment: I didn't record how to invoke this, and now I can't remember. Whatever I'm doing now, I'm doing it wrong, because this is always returning 0 as the smallest element.

Comment: Pfew! It took some starring at it, but found the bug in your code. It's the first character (0) which you duplicate and initialize registers `M` and `m`. But if in the input list no number is smaller than `m=0`, or no number is greater than `M=0`, then you get an incorrect result, because you artificially added 0 to the sample numbers. The solution is to replace that first 0 with `?d`, which reads the numbers and initializes `M` and `m` with the last number, thus making it a part of the sample. Then run the code like this: echo "8 _2 5"|dc -e "?ddsMsm....".

Comment: Wow, thanks, @seshoumara! I never would have noticed that! (I'd forgotten all about this question, too :P)

Answer (score 0):

### Bash + coreutils, 30 bytes

```sh
tr \  \\n|sort -n|sed '$p;1!d'
```

The sed script prints, after the input is sorted, the first and last integers.

Answer (score 0):

## C++14, 66 bytes

As unnamed lambda returning via reference parameters. Accepts any random access container of integers.

```c++
[](int&a,int&b,auto&C){a=b=C[0];for(auto x:C)a=x<a?x:a,b=x>b?x:b;}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```c++
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

auto f=
[](int&a,int&b,auto&C){
  a=b=C[0];
  for(auto x:C)
    a=x<a?x:a,
    b=x>b?x:b;
}
;

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,10,121,-12,100,100,100};
  int a;
  int b;
  f(a,b,v);
  std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 62 bytes

```
puts [lindex [set L [lsort -r [join $argv]]] 0]\ [lindex $L e]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYo7DoMwFMCu4oE1EqHldwduEN5QtRECIaiSgLj9IxObbTl9V9X/kSJunbefv3DRJ4ascQ8JE3DLPm8UnzCdIkIp4/MWA15UtcTWVLxosR2moqfB1Dl0GY193w)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 28 bytes

```
#((juxt first last)(sort %))
```

At least [juxt](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt) is mildly interesting.

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 110 Bytes

Long, but it doesn't use sort.

```
def m(a):
 d=a[0]
 if len(a)==1:return d,d
 b,c=m(a[1:])
 if b>=d>=c:return b,c
 if d>b:return d,c
 return b,d
```

Output is a tuple of the form (max, min). Probably the least computationally efficient way to get the max/min of an array (other than bongo sorting it  :P)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 97 bytes

```
def k(s):
 d=s[0]
 if s[1:]:
  a,b=k(s[1:])
  return(a+d+abs(a-d))/2,(b+d-abs(b-d))/2
 return d,d
```

Only clever part is that in python `[]` is falsy.
Only builtin used is abs.

It uses more builtins than the 110 byte python solution, and more bytes than the 26 byte solution using sort.

Answer (score 0):

## x86 opcode, 19 bytes

```
00: mov ebx, [esi]
02: mov edx, ebx
04: lodsd
05: cmp eax, ebx
07: cmovg ebx, eax
0A: cmp eax, edx
0C: cmovl edx, eax
0F: loop lp1
11: xchg eax, ebx
12: ret
```

Input: ECX(length), ESI(array)

Output: EAX(max), EDX(min)

Removing `xchg eax, ebx` makes 18B but output is not usual reg

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 87 bytes

```
	M =INPUT
	N =M
R	I =INPUT	:F(O)
	N =LT(I,N) I
	M =GT(I,M) I	:(R)
O	OUTPUT =N ' ' M
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYrLCsIwEEXXc79idiZgwNRWayE7HwTMREr6A67FLvx/0mmRu7nncH7f@T1/2lopcYjymgpIOCSMFP@ChrvJdtPPYuJeLEes@WOlpESDGS0y5aloz0F4p0u4ybXWA3yHBkec4Xu4Bhec4DoVvV7n2wU)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `h`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṠḲZ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT0lRTElQjklQTAlRTElQjglQjJaJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTdCMCUyQyUyMDE1JTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDMlMkMlMjA3JTJDJTIwMTglMkMlMjAtMiUyQyUyMDklMkMlMjA2JTJDJTIwLTUlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwOCUyQyUyMDklMkMlMjAtMTQlN0QmZmxhZ3M9aA==)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṡçht
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT0lRTElQjklQTAlQzMlQTdodCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSU3QjAlMkMlMjAxNSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwNyUyQyUyMDE4JTJDJTIwLTIlMkMlMjA5JTJDJTIwNiUyQyUyMC01JTJDJTIwMyUyQyUyMDglMkMlMjA5JTJDJTIwLTE0JTdEJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
ṠḲZ   # Implicit input
Ṡ     # Sort the list in ascending order
 Ḳ    # Bifurcate: duplicate and reverse
  Z   # Zip the two lists together
      # Implicit output of first item
```

```python
Ṡçht  # Implicit input
Ṡ     # Sort the list
 ç    # Parallelly apply:
  h   #  First item
   t  #  Last item
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 77 bytes

```swift
let f={(($0+[]).reduce(Int.max){$1>$0 ?$0:$1},$0.reduce(.min){$1<$0 ?$0:$1})}
```

The relatively obvious approach. I believe this is how the `max()` and `min()` methods are actually implemented for `Sequence` in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 3 bytes

```
SÞh
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJTw55oIiwiIiwiIiwiMy40LjIiXQ==)

sort, take the ends

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 20 bytes

```ruby
:sort|-[:first,:pop]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWW6yK84tKanSjrdIyi4pLdKwK8gtiIVI3TQsU3KKjDXQUDE11FIx0FIx1FMyBHAsdBV0gz1JHwQzIMgWLW4D5uoYmsVDNCxZAaAA)